# Passing radio button code in AsyncTask excute method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My problem is occurring in background.excute method while attempting to pass the value of male and female

```
name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NameTxt);
age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Agetext);
gender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);

int id = gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

male = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
female = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
 public void INSERT (View v){

MainBackground mainBackground=new MainBackground(this,this);
mainBackground.execute(name.getText().toString(),age.getText().toString(),
male.getText().toString(),female.getText().toString());
```

and the error is:
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: Please post your code and error in the question and not in attached images. Also try to actually ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You should findViewById individually for each radio button.

```
 male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male);// give id to male radio button as male if not give and similarly female for female button
 female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.female);
```

And you can pass the values like this :

Like this : Pass the value of male and female as boolean.

```
male.isChecked()
female.isChecked()
```

Answer (score 0):

radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

return only the reference of Selected Radio button

Comment: so how i  would  pass its value in execute method ??

Comment: forget execute method.....if you want to pass value of both male and female then i don't know why you are using radio group,because radio group are for getting value of radio button which is clicked,if still you want to get value of both then u need to initialize both radio button and den do what you want to do